# Run JSTL code stored into database field

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, render

I want to generate dynamic pages from fields that are stored into database.

If I store html code into database when I print this code into a JSP page the code is rendered by the navigator. But when I **store JSTL code into the database**, this code is not rendered by the servlet.

**Field in database**: `<h1>Hello<c:out value="World"><c:/out></h1>`

**JSP code**: `<c:out value="${module.content}">`

**Navigator response**: `Hello`

**HTML source code**: `<h1>Hello<c:out value="World"><c:/out></h1>`

So the JSTL code stored into database is not rendered by the servlet.

Is there any option to store JSTL code into database that is rendered bi the servlet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? Give us your context please.

Comment: I'm developing a simple CMS in Java and i want to store the "page content" (html and jstl) into database to be edited from a wysiwyg. The tecnology context is: EJB + JPA + Spring + Spring MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP files are "compiled" and transformed to a Java class file, so each value received by a JSP is just data, and cannot be added as part of the source code. I think what you are trying to do is the equivalent to this:

```
String s=" a + b";
int a=1;
int b=1;
System.out.println("s"); //It won't show "2"
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I know that i'm doing somenthing weird, but I'm wondering if there is any trick to re-run de JSP code :) Saludos desde Barcelona ;)

Comment: Any JSP file is recompiled is when the file is modified and the web container detects it, but definitely this is the wrong approach...
What about saving HTML templates in the database and process them before JSP receives them?